# how to instruct git to stop tracking outside directories?

Tags: git, github

For some reason, `$ git status` shows me changes to other directories:

[image]

How do I instruct git to stop tracking outside directories?

Comment: If they're tracked, they're obviously not outside of what it tracks.

Comment: Sounds like you did `git init .` or `git clone .` from a different directory than the one you wanted to do it from.

Comment: You must be in a subdirectory of your repository. `git status` shows the relative paths to any files.

Answer (score 2):

The files aren't outside of your repository; you're in a subdirectory of your repository.

```
$ find
.
./subdir
./subdir/bar.txt
./foo.txt

$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/ikegami/.git/

$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       foo.txt
#       subdir/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ cd subdir

$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ../foo.txt
#       ./
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

If your current directory is suppose to be your repository, you used `git init` instead of `git init subdir`, or you used `git clone url .` instead of `git clone url subdir`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the question is unclear, and what you actually want is:

```
git status .
```